# Combining jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I want to select #one, #two and the siblings of #two.  Is there a more elegant solution that what I have?

```
     $('#one, #two').click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
     });

     $('#two').siblings().click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [multiple selector exists](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/);

```
$("#one, #parentIdOfTwo > *").click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Lot faster, too.

Comment: Just note that this is not equivalent to the OPs code. It will also add the event handler to all descendants of `#parentIdOfTwo`. Better would be `#parentIdOfTwo > *`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, Mister Kling. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it took me a while to understand why we need to go one level up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Take a look I am using `andSelf` which add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set, really helpful in your case here.

```
$('#one').add($('#two').siblings().andSelf()).click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: like my solution :) I also thought about `andSelf` function but with no success

Comment: Heads up — there’s a small typo in your code sample: it should be `andSelf`, not `addSelf`.

Comment: @MathiasBynens - Thanks for letting me know before people dv it :P

Comment: @ShankarSangoli No worries :) It was obviously a typo, since your textual description used the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#one, #two').add($('#two').siblings()).click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$('#one, #two').add($('#two').siblings()).click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

…or:

```
$('#one').add($('#two').parent().children()).click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```